# OllyDbg - ReadFile API

Tags: ollydbg

I am learning reverse engineering (Lena's Reversing for Newbies) **Part 2**.
I'm confused about `ReadFile` API.

In Part 2,  I created a blank `Keyfile.dat` near application (without a key in it).

[image]

**pBytesRead :** addresses of number of bytes read

**Size** (Number of Bytes to Read) = 70 // number of bytes to read.

1. What is `-> 0`? In **pBytesRead** and **Buffer** the sign `->` appears with `0` and `00`. What does that mean?
2. What is Size (Number of Bytes to Read) = 70 means? Does it mean that the program should read `70` decimal?

I'm confused about this part.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What is `-> 0`? In **pBytesRead** and **Buffer** the sign `->` appears with `0` and `00`. What does that mean?

OllyDbg *wants to help you*, and offer you an additional info — *“What is currently at a given address?”*

- `address -> something` means that at the `address` is currently `something` — see the following pictures of memory dump.

(In the C-language parlance, address is a *pointer* to memory: “address *points to* something in memory,” so you may read `->` as “points to”.)

- `pBytesRead = reverseMe.402173 -> 0` means that at address `402173` is currently `0`,
- `Buffer = reverseMe.40211A -> 00` means that at address `40211A` is currently `00`.

**But why `0` in the first case, and `00` in the second one?**

Because - again - OllyDbg *wants to help you.* It is smart enough to correctly interpret *the meaning of the memory content* — in a given context — for you, a human:

- In the first case (`pBytesRead`), the expected data is a **number**, so it converts the double-word (4 consecutive bytes; LPDWORD in the documentation means Long Pointer to Double-Word) into a **decimal number** (`0` in your case):

  [image]
- in the second case (`Buffer`), the expected data is a **byte** (e.g. a character), so it shows it as an **ASCII-character** (e.g. `'p'`) if it is possible, or as **2 hexadecimal digits** otherwise (`00` in your case):

  [image]

---

> 2. What is Size (Number of Bytes to Read) = 70 means? Does it mean that the program should read `70` decimal?

Yes - more precisely, **at most (maximum)** 70 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info on **ReadFile** function at [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile).

The function signature from **MSDN**:

```
BOOL ReadFile(
  HANDLE       hFile,
  LPVOID       lpBuffer,
  DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

And if you agree with me, that how the function was called:

```
ReadFile(EAX, OFFSET 0x0040211A, 0x46, OFFSET 0x00402173, 0);
```

Here `0x46` (a hexadecimal number) is placed on **nNumberOfBytesToRead** parameter and we will read `70` (in decimal) characters.

- hfile - handle to the file, in this case it is assigned from [CreateFileA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) before.

Comment: Right, but what is 0x46 ? when the Keyfile.dat file is empty, why ReadFile read 0x46 or 70d ?

Comment: @Jason 0x46 is the value for nNumberOfBytesToRead parameter. That function will read 0x46 in hex characters.

Comment: Can you explain more? Where did this value come from? The ReadFile function read keyfile.dat and the value is 0x64? the 0x64 or 70d character is F in ascii. i confused :(

Comment: @jason look at the asciitable http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @jason It's 0x46 not 0x64! That's where you get confused, that value is for readFile function saying to read 70 characters from the file

Comment: Oh, my bad i mean 0x46. so why readfile read 70 character while the keyfile.dat is empty?

Comment: ReadFile takes a parameter x==NoofBytesToRead if the file has more x api will read only x if it is less than x it will read whatever is available since you created a blank file it will read 0 bytes if you fill garbage of 3 mb in your keyfile it will return you 70 decimal bytes from that garbage at the file seek position   if your file seek positon is at1.5 mb of thatgarbage it will return you 70 bytes from the 1.5 mb position